# Loop doubles the number of notes in note app

Tags: javascript, json

I'm making a small project for keeping notes. Everytime I click "Add a new note" note is added. After clicking second or more times the "Add" button, the loop keeps adding wrong amount of notes. First is 1 then 3,6,10 and so on.

document.querySelector('#newNoteBtn').addEventListener('click', onNewNote);

function onNewNote() {
const title = document.querySelector('#noteTitle').value;

```
const content = document.querySelector('#noteContent').value;
const note = {
    title: title,
    content: content,
    colour: '#ff1455',
    pinned: false,
    createDate: new Date()
}
notes.push(note);
console.log(note);

localStorage.setItem(lsNotesKey, JSON.stringify(notes));
const notesFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(lsNotesKey));

const convertedNotes = notesFromLocalStorage.map( note => {
    note.createDate = new Date(note.createDate);
    return note;
});
const notesContainer = document.querySelector('main');
for (const note of convertedNotes) {
    const htmlNote = document.createElement('section');
    const htmlTitle = document.createElement('h1');
    const htmlContent = document.createElement('p');
    const htmlTime = document.createElement('time');
    const htmlButton = document.createElement('button');

    htmlNote.classList.add('note');
    htmlTitle.innerHTML = note.title;
    htmlContent.innerHTML = note.content;
    htmlTime.innerHTML = note.createDate.toLocaleString();
    htmlButton.innerHTML = 'remove';

    htmlButton.addEventListener('click', removeNote);
    htmlNote.appendChild(htmlTitle);
    htmlNote.appendChild(htmlContent);
    htmlNote.appendChild(htmlTime);
    htmlNote.appendChild(htmlButton);
    notesContainer.appendChild(htmlNote);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You just never clean up your container, but adding whole set of nodes on each call.
Easiest way to solve that is to cleanup `notesContainer`:

```js
// ...
const notesContainer = document.querySelector('main');
notesContainer.innerHTML = ''; // <-- this line cleans up your container.
for (const note of convertedNotes) {
    // ...
```

This isn't optimal. From performance prospective, it better to add only newly created note, but this should hightlight the issue.

Comment: Given the use of localStorage, the implication is that the page will be reloaded at some point.  At which time, of course, the contents of the "main" container will be empty, so will need to be reloaded in its entirety anyway.  If that is the case, then clearing the innerHTML may be the simplest way anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are never clearing the contents of noteContainer:

```
// before the loop 
notesContainer.innerHtml = ""
```

Good luck!